# sum of sum of white noise

Tags: r, time-series

Let's say a_i are iid standard normal r.v.'s i=1,...,100

I'm attempting to visualize the time series z_t=sum from i=1 to t of(sum from j=1 to i of (a_i))

So, this is equivalent to z_t=z_(t-1) + sum from i=1 to t of a_i

Here is what I have so far:

```
set.seed(42)
a<-c(rnorm(100))
```

My thinking is to create a function z:{1,...100}->R that will perform this double sum. Then I can vectorize and graph the function across t=1 to t=100

UPDATED, here is what I ended up doing

```
a<-c(rnorm(100))
z<-function(t){
sum(cumsum(a)[1:t])
}
y<-1:100
for(i in 1:100){
y[i]<-z(i)
}
```

Comment: The definition of `z` looks as if you might want to calculate `cumsum(a)`?

Comment: cumsum(a) will be useful. So I'll have z_t=z_(t-1)+cumsum(a)[t].

Comment: My next step is to figure how to recursively create zt

Comment: What you are looking for is in fact `cumsum(cumsum(a))`